# start : job failed to start (MySQL)

Tags: mysql, database-administration, my.cnf

I went through various forum to increase the speed of the MySQL import and found that i have to increase the buffer size. So I added the following two lines in my.cnf file under `[mysqld]` section

```
user            = mysql
pid-file        = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
socket          = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
port            = 3306
basedir         = /usr
datadir         = /var/lib/mysql
tmpdir          = /tmp
lc-messages-dir = /usr/share/mysql
innodb_buffer_pool_size=4G
innodb_log_file_size=1G
```

After adding these two lines if I restart the `mysql` server it displays

```
start: Job failed to start
```

If i am wrong where should i add these lines?

Comment: How much ram does your system have in total?

Comment: 16GB RAM i5 4th Gen processeor

Comment: What does error log say?